# How can I get the context root in a custom RealmBase class in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat7, realm

In Tomcat 6, RealmBase provided a "path" field.  That apparently has been removed in Tomcat 7.  I need to know how to determine the value of the context root inside my authenticate() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get this by looking at the 6.0 source code of RealmBase.

Fortunately the RealmBase-derived instance has a "context" property containing the context root path:

```
this.getObjectName().getKeyProperty("context");
```